# Why is this just duplicating the last line in txt file?

Tags: java, arrays, txt

I am working on a specific part of this code that allows a user to change details about a project saved in a txt file. Each project is saved on an individual line like this:

```
1, Project House Tyson, Building Type: House, Project Address: 365 Long Ave, ERF Number: 12jk, Total Fee Charged: 1000, Amount Paid to Date: 900, Project Deadline: 01 October 2021, Project Contractor: Bob, Lead Architect: Ted, Client: Mike Tyson, Complete: No
```

If the user enters 'c', in the menu they will be asked to type in the name of the project and then to enter 'a' change the date. This all works fine except that instead of just changing the date in the desired line within the txt file, it replaces the project with a copy of the entire last line in the file.

It ends up looking something like this (note the project on line 3 is now a copy of line 5 but with the new date):

```
1, Project House Tyson, Building Type: House, Project Address: 365 Long Ave, ERF Number: 12jk, Total Fee Charged: 1000, Amount Paid to Date: 900, Project Deadline: 01 October 2021, Project Contractor: Bob, Lead Architect: Ted, Client: Mike Tyson, Complete: No
2, Project House Jordan, Building Type: house, Project Address: 75 Elgin Rd, ERF Number: mj23, Total Fee Charged: 1000, Amount Paid to Date: 900, 11 October 2021, Project Contractor: Bob, Lead Architect: Ted, Client: Mike Jordan, Complete: No
5, Project test3, Building Type: house, Project Address: 3i, ERF Number: 2k2k, Total Fee Charged: 10101, Amount Paid to Date: 2020, 05 October 2021, Project Contractor: ten, Lead Architect: dido, Client: kokolk, Complete: No
4, Project test2, Building Type: hh, Project Address: jhj, ERF Number: hjh, Total Fee Charged: hjh, Amount Paid to Date: hjh, Project Deadline: hjh, Project Contractor: hjh, Lead Architect: hjh, Client: hjh, Complete: No
5, Project test3, Building Type: house, Project Address: 3i, ERF Number: 2k2k, Total Fee Charged: 10101, Amount Paid to Date: 2020, Project Deadline: 01 December 2021, Project Contractor: ten, Lead Architect: dido, Client: kokolk, Complete: No
```

This is the main method where the user interacts with the menu. I don't think the problem is here, but just for some reference:

```
public class MenuV4 extends ExceptionHandling {

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, ParseException {
    
    //File object to store project info
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\CurrentProjects.txt");
        
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error at main");
    }
    
    //Options at main menu displayed to user
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease choose a number option from the menu below: "
                + "\na) View Projects"
                + "\nb) Add Project"
                + "\nc) Edit Project"
                + "\nd) Finalize a Project"
                + "\ne) View Incomplete Projects"
                + "\nf) View Overdue Projects"
                + "\ng) Exit program");
    
    //Checking user input is valid with string check method from Exception Handling class
    //fileCheck boolean makes sure that there is at least one project in the file object
    String userChoice = stringCheck("menu choice"); 
    boolean projects = fileCheck();
    
    if ((projects == true) && (userChoice.equals("a") || userChoice.equals("A"))) {  
        Projects object = new Projects();
        object.viewProjects();
        
    
    } else if (userChoice.equals("b") || userChoice.equals("B")) {  
        CreateProject setNew = new CreateProject();
        setNew.CreateProject();
        
    //Here is where the problem is, user enters 'c' to edit a project 
    } else if ((projects == true) && (userChoice.equals("c") || userChoice.equals("C"))) {  
        
        //User is prompted to enter the number of the project they would like to edit
        //This input is put through stringCheck
        //User can choose to change due date or fees paid
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the project you wish to update: \n");
        String projectInfo = stringCheck("project number");
        System.out.println("Would you like to:" + 
                "\na) Edit the project due date or" +
                "\nb} Edit the total amount paid of the fee to date?");
        
        //Again put through stingCheck
        String editChoice = stringCheck("edit choice");
        Projects obj1 = new Projects();
        int lineCount = obj1.loadProjects(projectInfo);
        obj1.updateProject(editChoice, lineCount);
```

The method that finds the project they are looking for looks like this:

```
public class Projects extends ExceptionHandling{

public int loadProjects(String projectInfo) {
    String[] info = new String[12];  
    int lineCount = 1;  
    
    // A new file object is created and a while loop used to run through lines in the test file.
    // Line info is then split and stored in the array.
    // While loop is exited if the second index in the array matches projectInfo parameter (typed in by user)
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\CurrentProjects.txt");  
        Scanner projectFile = new Scanner(file);
        
        while (projectFile.hasNextLine()) {  
            
            info = projectFile.nextLine().split(", "); 
            
            if ((info[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Project " + projectInfo)) || (info[1].equalsIgnoreCase(projectInfo))) {
                break;  
                
            } else {
                lineCount++; 
                
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        System.out.println("Error.");

    }
    return lineCount;  
}
```

The method to change the due date of the project looks like this and is also in the Projects class:
I think the problem is somewhere within this method.

```
public void updateProject (String editChoice, int lineCount) {
    
    ArrayList<String> infoArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] info = new String[12];
    int findLine = 1;
    
    // A file object is created and a while loop used to run through each line of the text file.
    // Each line of project information is added to the ArrayList.
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\CurrentProjects.txt");
        Scanner projectFile = new Scanner(file);
        
        while (projectFile.hasNextLine()) {
            infoArray.add(projectFile.nextLine());  
    
        }
    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        System.out.println("Error51");
    }
    
    //Create another file object.
    // Each line of the text file is run through and when the lineCount matches the findLine variable, then the line info is split.
    // That specific split line info is then stored in the info string array.
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\CurrentProjects.txt");
        Scanner projectFile = new Scanner(file);
        
        while (projectFile.hasNextLine()) {
            if (findLine == lineCount) {
                info = projectFile.nextLine().split(", ");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(info));
                
            } else if (findLine != lineCount) {  // Line count incremented if match is not made.
                findLine++;
            }
        }
    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }
    
     //If the user chose edit choice 'a', they are prompted for a new due date.
     //The new due date info is then inserted into index number 7 in the info array
     //The info array is then converted into a string, with extra characters removed ("[]")
     //The finalised string 'newLine' is then inserted into the correct index of the infoArray ArrayList (i.e. lineCount -1).
     //The same process is followed for edit choice 'b', except they are prompted for a new total amount, which is replaced at index 6 in the info array.
    if (editChoice.equals("a") || editChoice.equals("A")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a new project due date: ");
        String newDeadline = stringCheck("due date");
        info[7] = newDeadline;
        String newInfo = Arrays.toString(info);
        String changeLine = newInfo.replace("[", "");
        String newLine = changeLine.replace("]", "");
        infoArray.set(lineCount-1, newLine);
        
    } else if (editChoice.equals("b") || editChoice.equals("B")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a new total amount of the fee paid to date:");
        String newAmount = stringCheck("new total amount");
        info[6] = newAmount;
        String newInfo = Arrays.toString(info);
        String changeLine = newInfo.replace("[", "");
        String newLine = changeLine.replace("]", "");
        infoArray.set(lineCount-1, newLine);
        
    }
    
    
    //Re-write to the CurrentProjects.txt file.
    try {
        Formatter F = new Formatter("C:\\CurrentProjects.txt");
        for (String element : infoArray) {
            F.format("%s", element + "\r\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Project successfully updated.");  
        F.close();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");  
        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a debug point break on all lines containing System.out.println?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with editing txt files in the past, and I have also come across this exact problem.

I think the problem was that it was accessing a previous version of the info array list, in your case, infoArray.

So to fix this, I just had a method to remove all data from the infoArray, so no information could be accessed from a previous version of the txt file. This is the method:

```
public void removeInfo(ArrayList<String> info) {
    while(info.size() > 0) {
        info.remove(0);
    }
}
```

I’m not entirely sure where this remove method would belong in your code, but I hope it helps.